# accessing assets files from class

Tags: java, android, android-assets

i had this in my class: `private Context mCtx = getBaseContext();`

then the following code is my other class from which i want to use a file `dictionary.txt` from assets folder, I get `IO Exception`. Please Help

```
public class RandomStringGenerator {

    private final char[] generatedLetters = generate4().toCharArray();
        private int formedWordNo = 0;
        private final Set <String> formedWords = wordDictAvail(generatedLetters.toString());


        public Set<String> wordDictAvail (String inword){
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            int wa = 0;
                 int dictWordLn;
                 String dictWord;

                 try {
                        is =mCtx.getAssets().open("dictionary.txt");

                     Scanner scanner=new Scanner("is");

                 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                     String currChar;
                int i = 1;
                     dictWord = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            dictWordLn = dictWord.length();
                for (int a = 0; a <= dictWordLn-1 ; a++){
                    currChar = Character.toString(dictWord.charAt(a));
                    if (inword.contains(currChar)){
                        i =i*1;
                                     } else {i=i*2;}
                    }
                if (i==1){
                    set.add(dictWord);
                                     wa++;
                                     }

                                                                    }
                 scanner.close();
                 } catch(IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your MainActivity or any class which extends from Activity declare a static Context

```
private static Context con;
```

Assign in onCreate()

```
con = MainActivity.this;
```

From any other Activity reference this context like

```
Context presentContext = MainActivity.con
```

Let me know if that helps.